# PHP SQL Events?

Tags: php, sql, ajax, events, phpmyadmin

I have a instant updating comment system(This means that when anyone anywhere post, it updates instead of having to reload the page.) that uses setInterval to execute AJAX and send it to the server and reload the comments. So, the comments keep blinking. Anyway I need a way to only update the comments when it sees that a phpMyadmin SQL row has been added.

My site: http://learntc.net/index.php

Thanks for any help I get. Just comment if you need more information on something.

Comment: Instead of reloading the comments, use [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild) and related functions to add only the new content (don't have time for a full answer, sorry!).

Comment: Also stop using setInterval -> switch to function starting itself using setTimeout: setInterval is broken in all modern browsers when in an inactive tab (it will not fire when tab is inactive, will catch up firing up multiple times when tab becomes active).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you load the comments, each record will have an ID. You will know the highest record ID that is loaded on the page.

When your JS timer makes the ajax call, have it send that highest loaded ID back to server. Your query can then specify only to load records where the ID is higher than the supplied value. You will then only get records that are newer than the ones on the page.

Then, when this data is sent back to your page, rather than replacing the whole comment block, simply append the new data onto the end of the existing comment block.

This will prevent the existing comments from having to be reloaded. It will prevent the flickering, and will also make your SQL queries more efficient, and save you bandwidth from sending the same data over and over again.

Hope that's enough of an explanation to get you started.

Finally, one other thing. Off topic, but I should mention it: I would recommend avoiding the Javascript `setInterval()` function. Use `setTimer()` instead, and re-trigger it on each iteration.

The reason for this is that `setInterval()` can get itself into problems if any JS code causes a delay. For example, if you have an `alert()` that the user leaves on screen for a length of time, the `setInterval()` calls that would have happened while the `alert()` was blocking the system will all get stacked up and will all be fired in quick succession one after the other as soon as JS gets control back. This can be a serious problem. If you use `setTimer()` instead, you will avoid this issue.

For a better explaination, read here: http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#other.timeouts

Comment: Okay, one last thing. How would I get the id off the comment. If I get it in jQuery. It should get the first object with that id/class right?IE: var id = $("#comment").attr("id");

Comment: When you create the HTML, include the SQL ID in the HTML code somewhere. Possibly use a data attribute: `data-id='123'`. Then you can use jQuery's data property: `$().data('id')`.

Comment: Thanks very much Spudley! // Nice name :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can have the AJAX request send the id of the last comment the user sees (you can keep it in a hidden input or as an id of a div, etc.). Using this you can return only new comments to the user. In the response function you can append any new comments to the list of the ones you already have. This will prevent the blinking of all comments and will definitely be healthy for your bandwidth ;)

Answer (score 1):

1. Return either the last comment id or its timestamp (if table has the time recorded).
2. For the next Ajax request, send the above as paramater and query only those records which are greater than the existing value.
3. Append the results.

Comment: How do I get the last comment id?

Answer (score 0):

I did a system like that. Code itself is large enough, but main idea (the simplest one) is to collect ids of comments available on page(or maybe it's enough to use latest comment time) and load comments not available on a page for now. (pass a marker in AJAX call and use it in your query to get only items you really need)
If your comments are always added - you can simply load a piece of HTML and add it to the end of comments list. If comment may be removed and you should show that - it is better to use JSON.

About your current implementation - why do you need so frequent update? I see it happens each second or so. You just load your server. Also - you do not need to to return html, body etc. That is just a garbage in your case. Also - there is a jquery script which is included into response body. Why??? You already have it there.

Take a look at other AJAX functions of jquery. `.load` is not the only one.

Comment: About what? There is no simple solution which you can call with one line of code. Everything depends on your needs. If you have only new comments always added to the end - print its ids with data-id="id" attribute and access it with .data('id') function of jquery. There is :last selector in jQuery. You can use it to get last item in your list (something like:`$(".comment:last").data('id')`) and pass it as additional parameter of request (see `[data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)`option). And than use it in your sql query to get items with id > $latest_id